# How to wait for setState prior to executing next steps that rely on setState values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, state

I have the following useEffect hook within my react app with useState:

```
  const [jobTypes, setJobTypes] = useState([]);

  const getJobTypes = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/job-types');
      const jsonData = await response.json();

      setJobTypes(jsonData);

      const jobTypeName = jobTypes.find(jobType => jobType.ret === jobDetails.jobType)
      console.log("jobTypeName: ", jobTypeName)

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    getJobTypes();
  }, []);
```

The issue I am facing is that I need to wait for `setJobTypes(jsonData)` to complete prior to performing my find statement, i.e:

```
const jobTypeName = jobTypes.find(jobType => jobType.ret === jobDetails.jobType)
```

as I am getting back an undefined for `jobTypeName`

Can anyone assist with the best approach to achieve the above as I only want to execute my `array.find` when `jobTypes` is available

Comment: use `jsonData` instead of `jobTypes`: `jsonData.find(....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is using `jsonData` instead of `jobTypes`

```
const jobTypeName = jsonData.find(jobType => jobType.ret === jobDetails.jobType)
```